# cat /proc/devices on Galaxy Note shows a device named roccat

Tags: cyanogenmod, terminal

Whats that supposed to be?

cat /proc/devices on

Galaxy Note N7000 JellyBeer 4 build from 15.March (CM10.1 based with per app dpi features, more similar to cm than to paranoidandroid)

Char devices:

...
249    roccat 
...

I have a device named roccat on my desktop, where its fully understandable to have it since my mouse is made by roccat.
But this was taken from terminal emulator on the phone which is not connected to the desktop in any way.

Comment: is it a bluetooth mouse?

Comment: no its  a wired one